# I need to seperate the checked and unchecked checkbox. Please any one help me out

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to seperate the checked and unchecked check box from set of check boxes. i have done half-of-work but i can't able to separate the checked and unchecked checkbox. please help me out.

Below example has the merge button. when clicked on the merge button. it has to be separate the checked and unchecked checkbox.

```
$('document').ready( function() {
         var b = $('#hid').val();
                 for (var i=0; i<b; i++) {
    var data ="<li><input type='checkbox' id='"+i+"'>Example"+i+"</li>";
                   $('#aa').append(data);
                   //$('td').css({'border-right':'1px solid red', ''});
                   $('.checklist').append(data);
              }  

                //var a = $('input[type="checkbox"]').length;
                //$('input[type="checkbox"]').attr("checked");
                //if ($(this).is(':checked')) {

                //}


/* for (j=0; j<a; j++)
                {
                        var che = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length;
                        alert (che);
                        if(che > 3))
                        {
                                alert ('this is 2');
                        } else {
                                alert('you clicked more than four');
                        }
                }*/


                $('#mer').click( function() {
                 var che = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').filter(":checked").length;
                 //alert($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').filter(":not(:checked)").length);
   $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').attr('disabled', true);  

                });


/*  
   for (var j=0; j<=b; j++) {
                 function isEven(j) {
           if (j%2 == 0)
             alert(j);
                          return true;
             else
               return false;
          }  
                 }
*/  


/* $(function() {
          $('input[type="checkbox"]').bind('click',function() {  
                          if($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length == 2) {
                                 $(':checked').attr('disabled', true);
               }
          });
        });  
*/



});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.wrapper {
 width:900px;
 height:auto;
 margin:0 auto;
}
.checklist {
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
}
 ul.checklist {
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
}
 ul.checklist li {
 list-style-type:none;
}
.dull {
        color:#ccc;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<input type="hidden" name="no. of checkbox" value="15" id="hid"/>
<ul class="checklist">
</ul>
<input type="button" value="merge" id="mer" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The commented code It's kind of messy, Do you really need It? Can you improve your goal explanation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like:

```
var unchecked = [];
var checked = [];
jQuery.each($('input[type="checkbox"]'), function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        checked.push(this);
    }
    else {
        unchecked.push(this);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. i need one more help that how to display the checked and unchecked element.

Answer (score 2):

You can select checked with:

```
$(":checkbox:checked")
```

And not checked with:

```
$(":checkbox:not(:checked)")
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#mer').click( function() {
  var checked = [];
  var unchecked = [];  
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
    if( this.checked ){
      checked.push(this);
    }else{
      unchecked.push(this);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand what you want to accomplish. From your comments it seems to me that you need something like this (replace your `div.wrapper` with mine and add the **jQuery** code before the end of your `body`):

**HTML code (`div.wrapper`) :**

```
<div class="wrapper">
<form action="#" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <ul class="checkboxes">
        <li><label for="chk_1">chk_1</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="chk1" value="" id="chk_1">
        </li>
        <li><label for="chk_2">chk_2</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="chk2" value="" id="chk_2">
        </li>
        <li><label for="chk_3">chk_3</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="chk3" value="" id="chk_3">
        </li>
        <li><label for="chk_4">chk_4</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="chk4" value="" id="chk_4">
        </li>
        <li><label for="chk_5">chk_5</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="chk5" value="" id="chk_5">
        </li>
        <li><label for="chk_6">chk_6</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="chk6" value="" id="chk_6">
        </li>
    </ul>

    <input type="button" value="merge" id="mer" />
</form>
```

**jQuery code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$('document').ready( function() {
    $('#mer').click( function() {
        var checked = $(':checkbox:checked').parents("li").remove();
        checked.insertBefore($(".checkboxes li:first"));
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: hi microspino

This is my requirement that when clicked on the merge button how to sort the multiple selected checkboxes in ascending order followed by the unchecked boxes.

Comment: What do you mean for "ascending order"? Does it mean first checked = first in list?